# Using Webkit for building iOS Native UI

Tags: iphone, ios

Had read somewhere that we can build native UI with the Webkit Framework... Is it possible by any means?? 
    Or the use of webkit framework only limited for Webviews in iOS development?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

You will not be able to use native controls with Webkit. However, if you want native looking controls in a UIWebView, try [Sencha Touch](http://www.sencha.com/products/touch/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use UIWebView in your native app but everything inside it will be HTML/CSS will all its limitations like security, limited and not that native look-n-feel, etc.